# How to implement pagination in firestore specially in firebase official Friendly eats app?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I search web a lot as well as stackoverflow but my question is remaining same. I tried a lot but not working.

After a lots of try, I wrote this code but its working only one-way. I mean I can scroll up and pagination working nicely (with some flashes :) ) but its not allow me to scroll up. I mean new items are adding continuously but I cannot browse previous items of recyclerview.

Here's my code

```
        mQuery = mFirestore.collection("artists")
            .orderBy(Artist.FIELD_ARTISTNAME, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .limit(LIMIT);

    fillList(mQuery);

    mQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "first page loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                    if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                        isScrolling = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    int firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, firstVisibleItem + " and " + visibleItemCount + " and " + totalItemCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (isScrolling && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemReached) {

                        isScrolling = false;

                        mQuery = mFirestore.collection("artists")
                                .orderBy(Artist.FIELD_ARTISTNAME, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                                .startAfter(lastVisible)
                                .limit(LIMIT);

                        mQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                fillList(mQuery);
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "next page loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                if (task.getResult().size() < LIMIT) {
                                    isLastItemReached = true;
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            mRestaurantsRecycler.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
        }
    });
```

Here's code for fillList function

```
    public void fillList(Query myQuery) {
    // RecyclerView
    mAdapter = new ArtistAdapter(myQuery, this) {
        @Override
        protected void onDataChanged() {
            // Show/hide content if the query returns empty.
            if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                mRestaurantsRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mEmptyViewText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.message_no_results));
                mEmptyViewExit.setTag("noRecords");
                mEmptyViewExit.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_records_button));
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mRestaurantsRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            // Show a snackbar on errors
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                    "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    mRestaurantsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRestaurantsRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Kindly check code properly and then mark duplicate. Its not duplicate. My question is totally different and UNIQUE in stack overflow. I search everything properly and then ask this question.

Comment: @Alex Mamo I used my code as per your tutorials which is available in youtube but my code structure is little bit different then your code. Please look into my code and guide me. Please

Comment: People at Stackoverflow are free for marking question as duplicate but they are busy for answering the question. :)